# Apache commons CSV parser

Tags: csv, java-8, apache-commons

How to read values from the CSV without relaying on the order?

Even reading with `.get("headerName")` internally relies on the order. Anyone found a better way to handle this problem?

Example csv

```
header1,header2
1111111,2222222
```

Comment: could you post the format of your CSV? it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wrote my own logic to map csv to a map. Used apache csv parser that has very basic functionality though.

```
 public List<Map<String, Object>> getMapFromCSV(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        try {
            CSVParser parser = parseCSV(multipartFile.getInputStream());
            return getMap(parser.getRecords(), parser.getHeaderMap());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RunTimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> getMap (List<CSVRecord> records, Map<String, Integer> headers) {
        Map<Integer, String> headerMap = formatHeaderMap(headers);
        List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < records.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                CSVRecord record = records.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < record.size(); j++) {
                    map.put(headerMap.get(j), record.get(j));
                }
                data.add(map);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RunTimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    private Map<Integer, String> formatHeaderMap(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        map.forEach((k , v) -> {
            data.put(v, k);
        });
        return data;
    }

    private CSVParser parseCSV(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            return new CSVParser(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                    .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                    .withSkipHeaderRecord()
                    .withTrim());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RunTimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial.html#column-selection) to select the columns you are interested in getting.

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.selectFields("e", "d", "b", "a");

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

//all rows will have the values of your selected headers only, in the order you defined above.
List<Record> allRecords = parser.parseAllRecords(new File("/path/to/your.csv"));
```

Hope this helps

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem and found a solution! You need to specify the .withHeaders() call without any parameters to allow the library to compute the correct indexes for the columns. For example:

```
CSVParser.parse(inputStream, Charset.defaultCharset(), 
    CSVFormat.DEFAULT
             .withTrim()
             .withHeader() // note, do not specify any columns here
)
```